# Training features with different dimensions

Tags: keras, deep-learning, layer

I have two types of features that should be concatenated and trained, features are as follow:

1. Images with dimension (277,217,3)
2. vector of real numbers (40,1)

What I did is after training the model on all images, I extracted the output of predict() function of all samples, this outputs vector, then I concatenated this vector with the real number features. But the problem is when I trained the values of predict() alone, the result was lower than the base model's result.

So I am trying to add the features after the convolutional layers while the model is training
[image: this what am thinking about. All features will be trained together]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's not very clear what you need. Are you asking how to concatenate the two layers? If so, take a look at `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate`  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate

Comment: I Need to add features in the middle of the model while training. These features are real numbers while the main features are images